# Format of the shorttitle field

Tags: biblatex, formatting, citing, biber

I would like to change the format of the shorttitle when it appears (i.e. when the article has been already cited).

I used the function `\DeclareFieldFormat` to change the format of the title itself, but a simple adaptation of

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings]{title}{\gui{#1\isdot}}
```

into

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings]{shorttitle}{\gui{#1\isdot}}
```

does not work.

Here is the bib items from the .bib file:

```
@article{bollman1966cannophori,
     title = {The Cannophori and the March Festival of Magna Mater},
     shorttitle = {The Cannophori},
     author={Bollmann, B.},
     journal = {Transactions and Proceedings of the American Philological Association},
     volume = {97},
     number = {},
     pages = {193-202 },
     year = {1966},
     note = {}
}
@book{suetone,
   title = {Suétone, Vie de douze Césars},
   editor={Bollmann, B.},
   editortype={compiler},
   year={1998},
   publisher={Philip von Zabern},
   address = {Mayence},
   note = {seult ULB}
 }
```

And here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

\usepackage[backend=biber, 
            sorting=nyt, 
            block=space, 
            citestyle=verbose-trad2,
            bibstyle=verbose-trad3,
            citepages=omit  
            ]{biblatex}

\usepackage{csquotes}       

\addbibresource{Biblio.bib}

\newcommand{\gui}[1]{«~#1~»}  
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings]{title}{\gui{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings]{shorttitle}{\gui{#1\isdot}}

\begin{document}

Text text\footcite{bollman1966cannophori}.

Other text\footcite{suetone}. 

Other other text\footcite{bollman1966cannophori}.
\end{document}
```

This example gives [image: result]

My problem is that in the third citation the French quotes are set without spaces before and after the shorttitle (while they are in the case of the first citation, i.e. when the title is printed).

Comment: Note that `citestyle=verbose-trad2, bibstyle=verbose-trad3,` is equivalent to `style=verbose-trad2`, but the latter is easier to read, both styles actually have as `bibstyle` just `authortitle`. If you use `csquotes` and `polyglossia`, you should be able to make all quotes have a space after them by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out that `shorttitle` should be replaced by `citetitle`.

So in fact this

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings]{citetitle}{\gui{#1\isdot}}
```

works, even if I do not really understand why...

Comment: Indeed, `biblatex` uses the `citetitle` format for `title` and `shorttitle` when they appear in a citation.